# what is the difference between charity/foundation/cause/trust

Tags: differences

I looked at dictionary but i couldn't understand the difference between charity/foundation/cause/trust with simple examples please

Answer (score 2):

A **cause** is, in this context, an issue or group to whom someone might give their financial, political, legal or physical support. For example, supplying clean water in developing countries; teaching children to read; researching treatments for diseases; feeding the homeless.

A **charity** is an organisation which provides this support to a chosen cause or set of causes. For example, Water.Org works to supply clean water, Cancer Research UK supports research into cancer treatment, and Room to Read focuses on child literacy. Charities can directly collect money and provide money or resources towards a cause, they can work to raise awareness of a cause, they can work to influence governments to support a cause, or any combination of these.

**Foundations** and **trusts** are the most similar of these, with the distinction being primarily a legal one. Both are ways to manage or take care of a sum of money, with a foundation being an organisation in its own right, and a trust being a group of people (who may themselves hire employees to form an organisation!) Trusts and foundations can also, just to confuse things, be charitable, and can work to support causes. For example, the Bill & Melinda Gates Foundation works on various health and development causes around the world. However, many trusts simply exist to manage the money of a wealthy person, family or group.